# Arista 7048T-A Enabling ethernet ports, interface does not exist

Tags: configuration, command-line-interface, switch, ethernet, putty

On the switch I'm trying to enable the ethernet ports for internet access to no avail. After setting the DNS, Default gateway I'm now trying to enable 2 ethernet ports on the switch (port 1 and 2 but it can be any). After sending commands and writing the config plugging an ethernet cable from the switch to the pc gives no blinking activity lights, neither does plugging a cable from the wall with a known working connection give any lights. These are the commands i used.

```
switch(config)#interface ethernet 1
! Interface does not exist. The configuration will not take effect until the module is inserted.
switch(config-if-Et1)#no shutdown
switch(config-if-Et1)#no switchport mode
switch(config-if-Et1)#write
Copy completed successfully.
switch(config-if-Et1)#exit
switch(config)#
```

Running these commands with a cable plugged in yields no difference. Rebooting makes no difference. What does "Interface does not exist" mean? What is the module being referenced? Did I miss any required actions?

Edit:
Running commands to view statuses yield strange results:
The output of `show hardware port-group` -

```
switch(config)#show hardware port-group
% Unavailable command (not supported on this hardware platform)
```

The output `show interfaces status` -

```
switch(config)#show interfaces status
switch(config)#
```

It doesn't write out anything. Reading the [manual](https://www.arista.com/assets/data/docs/Manuals/EOS-4.17.0F-Manual.pdf#G12.1144090), its supposed to give out something.

Comment: Post the output of `show interfaces status`. _Interface does not exist_ means...well your referenced interface does not exist, I assume you just gave the wrong interface name/ ID.

Comment: @Lenniey edited

Comment: You are in the wrong command mode, you need to be in `EXEC`, not in `Global Configuration`, use `end` and/ or `disable` to reach `EXEC` mode and enter the command again

Comment: Just tried again running it from `switch>` and `switch#` yields same results.

Comment: What EOS version are you running?

Comment: From `show running-config` - `! device: switch (unknown-hardware, EOS-4.15.6M)`

Comment: Oh, can't help you there. Your switch may be broken if this persists after reboot and/ or factory reset. These switches are EOL, so you probably won't get support for it, sorry.